# Trouble with Mattermost verification email

Tags: mattermost

I know there were several questions about this already, but I couldn't find any steps to resolve it myself. I'm trying to create a Mattermost account via chat.civicrm.org for the first time, and it's not sending the verification emails even though it says it has. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you should register at civicrm.org and then use that same accountname and password for mattermost.

Comment: I tried that first, and it didn't work. I have an account on civicrm.org that I'm able to log into and receive verification emails from without a problem. I wasn't able to use that same login for Mattermost, I had to create a new account, and I can't move forward because I'm not receiving verification emails from them. Any ideas on what to do next? Thank you for the response!

Comment: I'm still not receiving any verification emails, and I'm stuck and not sure what to do next. Would someone be able to post my question to the infrastructure channel on Mattermost? I'd really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: I have posted your question on mattermost. And asked bgm to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were problems with the email notifications and the issue should now be resolved. If the problem persists, you can email me at: mathieu at civicrm.org.